# Unity adds extra permissions to manifest file after exporting a project

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to unity and I noticed that when exporting a unity project, unity adds extra/unwanted permissions to the android manifest file. We tried to use tools:node="remove" but it didn't help. Currently, we are using double flip build process, but we also trying to avoid using that for long. Preview is set to false in EditorBuildScript.cs

[The highlighted part of the image is showing the extra permissions added by unity at build time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eikqw.png)

Comment: What permissions? Unity will add permissions it thinks are necessary depending on features you use and the player settings. https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.2/Documentation/Manual/android-permissions-in-unity.html Plugins may also add permissions based on their manifests.

Comment: Thank you!! I've added an image to my post to show the permissions